# Salesforce query returns only 2000 data

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to execute a query to fetch full record of user roles from salesforce using SOAP.
But I am getting only 2000 records out of 17,000.

I want to display all roles and its corresponding level as shown below.

RoleID  ParentID    Level   Has subordinate?

1111      2222          1           yes

As i am getting a portion of data , I am not able to iterate and calculate the actual Level.

Please help me on this or suggest me a better method.

Thanks,

Comment: You can query more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

API returns the results in chunks / batches. You're supposed to call [`queryMore()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm) function to fetch next "page" of results.

There are [LOADS of questions about it already](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=salesforce%20querymore), including some language-specicic answers (if you're using the libraries for Ruby for example). And there are [even better ones](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=querymore%20soap) at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com):

1. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/35011/get-more-than-2000-with-soap-and-php
2. Check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/924/is-there-a-way-to-query-role-hierarchy too
3. And if you have thousands of records (and if your app can handle bigger chunks!) maybe you should read about [bulk API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/).

Comment: Great news, glad I helped! Can you please tick the checkbox on the left so the answer gets marked as accepted and the question goes "off the radar"?